# Can not send large message with Office 365 REST API

Tags: ajax, base64, office365api, faraday, office365-restapi

I'm using JavaScript to make a POST request to create a message to Office 365 with xhr (Or using Faraday gem to make POST request - Ruby on Rails).My flow is encode file to base64 and create a JSON contain all attachments(encoded) then POST to `https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/sendmail`.

```
var endpointUrl = "https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/sendmail";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", endpointUrl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(result));
}
```

This code can send message with about 22,5MB attachments, but if all attachments have more than 23MB, I got 404 error reponse and the cosole write:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/sendmail. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Alr set `message size restrictions` to max `153600`
Could someone help me? Thank you !

Comment: What is the size of the payload (message + attachments) after encoding for the failure and success cases?

Comment: @VenkatAyyadevara-MSFT Sorry, now I got my payload's size. After encode 20mb files with empty mail body, i got about 27mb size of payload and `Fail`. It's successfully with 15mb files (after encode, size of payload is 19mb).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Can you please try your request to outlook.office365.com instead of outlook.office.com and see if the 27mb payload and 19mb payload messages succeed?

Comment: @VenkatAyyadevara-MSFT Hi, while I'm using outlook.office365.com, I got new error when try to send 30mb attachments.<br>
`The maximum number of bytes allowed to be read from the stream has been exceeded. After the last read operation, a total of 38798336 bytes has been read from the stream; however a maximum of 38797312 bytes is allowed.`

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Will check with my team and get back to you.

Comment: @VenkatAyyadevara-MSFT Thank you. I will wait for you.

Comment: Thank you for your patience.  I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does look like you are running into a limit on the max size of the payload.  The limit currently is 37 MB and a lower limit is being enforced through outlook.office.com.  We have opened a work item to increase this limit to allow the max attachment size we can store in Office 365 (150 MB), but you will need to wait for that to be completed before you can send messages of the sizes you are attempting to send.

Comment: Hi Venkat, do you have any information about this? We are reading in the send folder, the folder has a mail with an attachment that is over 40 MB but the API can't read the folder.