# What is the difference between outlook.office365 and outlook.office

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office365, outlook-restapi

I'm using the Outlook REST API v2 with url **https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/**. I was not able to add a big file attachment (20MB) to a message. Then i found this question here: [Can not send large message with Office 365 REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595303/can-not-send-large-message-with-office-365-rest-api) and as suggested there i tried using outlook.office365.com and my post request was successful.

So my question here is: what is actually the difference between outlook.office365 and outlook.office ? Are they exposing different APIs or are there some restrictions to one or the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not send large message with Office 365 REST API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595303/can-not-send-large-message-with-office-365-rest-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APIs exposed are the same. As Venkat noted in the other issue, there's just a lower file size limit on outlook.office.com.

Comment: Hi Jason, this is slightly off topic, but can you look [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342729/make-office365-restapi-a-synonym-for-office365api) to try and help me get some Office365 Tags unified?